# htaccess - rewriting API requests to "api.php" and other requests to "web.php"

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm testing some stuffs on Apache server and PHP. at the root of my project, I have this
`.htaccess` configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /react/

# API requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/react/api/
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ routes/api.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]

# Non-API requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/react/api/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ routes/web.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to redirect requests starting with `api` to `api.php` and others to `web.php`. However, with the current configuration, all requests are being redirected to `web.php`. I haven't been able to identify the issue. Please help me.

(Sorry if there are any errors in my text; I'm not fluent in English.)"

I tried some much things, for example I did this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /react/

# API requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/react/api/
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ routes/api.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]

# Non-API requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/react/api/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ routes/web.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This worked, but when I have this kind of URL `localhost/react/client/something` it didn't work.

Comment: If you have the .htaccess on your root level, then why would the path RewriteRule matches against, start with just `api/` - when the actual URL you are requesting is something like `/react/api/foo`? This should be `^react/api/(.*)$` then. (And the RewriteCond is superfluous in that case, because the rule pattern already makes is apply only when the REQUEST_URI matches that format, so no need to check the same thing twice.)

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Yeah you are right, the RewriteCond is superfluous.

The RewriteRue start with api/ because of the RewriteBase /react/. I wanted to specify from where the rewriterule should be apply

Comment: "The RewriteRue start with api/ because of the RewriteBase /react/" - The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ starts with `api/` because the `.htaccess` file is inside the `/react` subdirectory ("the root of the project", not the "document root"). The `RewriteBase` directive only affects relative _substititution_ strings. And if the `.htaccess` file is inside the `/react` subdirectory then the `RewriteBase` directive is not required at all. @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # Non-API requests
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/react/api/
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ routes/web.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> this worked, but when i have this kind of url 'localhost/react/client/something' it didn't work

Because the regex `^([^/]+)$` only matches URLs with a single path segment. eg. `/foo` and `/bar`, but not `/foo/bar` or `/client/something` (your example).

It also doesn't match the directory itself (an empty URL-path), so requests for `localhost/react/` would also fail.

However, you do need an an additional rule (or condition) to prevent an additional pass by the rewrite engine. Or use the `END` flag (Apache 2.4) instead of `L`. Without this, an additional loop by the rewrite engine results in either:

1. the request being rewritten to `routes/web.php` a second time, at which point the rewrite engine terminates.
2. OR, rewritten requests to `routes/api.php` end up being rewritten to `roues/web.php` instead during the 2nd pass.

For example, use something like the following instead:

```
# /react/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Fail early if "api.php" or "web.php" already requested
RewriteRule ^routes/(api|web)\.php$ - [L]

# API requests
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) routes/api.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]

# Non-API requests
RewriteRule (.*) routes/web.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]
```

(Although, it would seem from your existing answer that the `controller=$1` query string is not required on the second rule. In which case, the `QSA` flag is not required either, since the query string is passed through by default.)

Note also that since the `.htaccess` file would seem to be in the `/react` subdirectory then the `RewriteBase` directive is not required.

However, an additional concern with this is that all static assets (CSS, JS, images, etc.) are going to be rewritten to `web.php` as well, unless these are hosted somewhere else entirely?

Comment: wow thank you for your response. I understand a lot more now

Answer (score 0):

I knew that I had to revise my regex expressions

I did it and it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /react/

# API requests
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ routes/api.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]

# Non-API requests
RewriteRule ^(?!.*api).*$ routes/web.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The negative lookahead `(?!.*api)` is rather too broad (and not strictly required). It excludes any URL that simply contains the string `api`. However, you do need an additional rule/condition to prevent an additional rewrite by mod_rewrite. An additional concern is that any static assets are also going to be rewritten to `web.php` - is that the intention? See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77901432/369434) that expands on these points.